# ReflectionClass::getProperty for a private property in an inhertited class

Tags: php, reflection

Suppose you have a class A with a private property $a, and a class B which inherits from that.
If I use ReflectionClass::getProperty on an instance of B, I get a fatal error, that the property doesn't exists. This makes sense, as it is it a private method. However, ReflectionClass::hasProperty returns true, nonetheless. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug seems to be about this problem : [Bug #47808 : hasProperty inconsistent with getProperty and new ReflectionProperty](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47808)

It's been marked as "fixed in SVN" on August the 4th, which is quite recent ; maybe it's solved in a version of PHP more recent than the one you are using ?

Well, doesn't seem to appear in the [PHP 5 ChangeLog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) -- so I'm guessing that fix has not been released yet... Or not documented or anything...