# Why doesn't ReflectionClass read the private properties of its parents when made accessible?

Tags: php, reflection

I have an abstract class and an implementing class:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    public function __construct() { }

    public function get($property) {
        $rc = new \ReflectionClass($this);
        $p = $rc->getProperty($property);
        $p->setAccessible(true);
        return $p->getValue($this);
    }

    public function set($property, $value) {
        $rc = new \ReflectionClass($this);
        $p = $rc->getProperty($property);
        $p->setAccessible(true);
        $p->setValue($this, $value);
        return $this;
    }
}

abstract class MetadataClass extends AbstractClass {
    private $metadataA;
    private $metadataB;
}

class ActualClass extends MetadataClass {
    private $realField1;
    private $realField2;
}
```

I declare and try to get/set a property from/to the child class:

```
$ac = new ActualClass();
$ac->set('metadataA', 'Hello World');
echo $ac->get('metadataA');
```

And I receive:

```
ReflectionException 0 Property metadataA does not exist in AbstractClass.php on line 13
```

Is this a limitation of the `ReflectionClass` or am I missing something? Is this [still a bug in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495600/reflectionclassgetproperty-for-a-private-property-in-an-inhertited-class?rq=1)?

Comment: Is `ClassImpl` expected to guess that it extends `AbstractClass`? I'm surprised you don't get an error about referencing `parent` in the `ClassImpl` constructor when PHP has no idea who/what the parent is

Comment: Sorry, that was an oversight; since I wrote the example code in my question, with the exception of the get/set methods, I was bound to forget something. `ClassImpl` does indeed extend `AbstractClass`.

Comment: Aside from the namespacing in versions prior to PHP 5.3, this seems to work as expected - http://3v4l.org/pb74C#tabs

Comment: Hmm, there must be something special about the actual classes that I've forgot to add. I'll look into it within the next hour.

Comment: I created [a 3v4l here](http://3v4l.org/5tbfb). I was able to reproduce the issue. Basically, I have three levels in my class hierarchy and I cannot access any properties on higher levels.

Comment: I suspect that the issue is your $metadataA and $metadataB properties being private to the MetadataClass which means they're not visible/accessible properties to either AbstractClass (executing the reflection requests) or to ActualClass (the concrete instance)

Comment: That's what `$p->setAccessible(true)` is for. I only have control over the child class. The parent classes are in a `phar`. Otherwise, what's the point of [setAccessible](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php)?